# Clojure defrecord serialization ClassNotFoundException

Tags: serialization, clojure, record

I was trying to serialise one of my records to a human readable format. While serialising using Java serialiser worked fine I am trying to use print-dup. The problem I am facing is that while writing the record goes fine reading the record results in  clojure.lang.LispReader$ReaderException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: common.dummy.Doodh. Am I messing up the namespaces or something?
Please note that this is not a problem with Java serialisation.
Code below in the simplest form

```
(ns common.dummy)

   (defrecord Doodh [id name])

   (defn output [filename obj]
    (def trr(map->Doodh {:id "moooh" :name "Cows"}))
    (def my-string (binding [*print-dup* true] (pr-str trr)))
    (spit filename my-string)
   )

   (defn pull [filename]
     (def my-data (with-in-str (slurp filename) (read)))
     (println my-data)
   )
```

text file contents:

```
#common.dummy.Doodh["moooh", "Cows"]
```

Comment: What is a Doodh, by the way?

Comment: Cannot reproduce error. Report `*clojure-version* and your test which generated the exception.

Comment: Doodh = Milk. Hence the moohs and cows.

Comment: @A.Webb Webb Clojure version {:major 1, :minor 5, :incremental 1, :qualifier nil}. Not quite sure if it is relevant but I am using ring, lacij, tikkba. As I had noted earlier this works fine when I am doing a pure Java based serialisation.

Please do note the namespace. The error I reported is not from REPL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Don't use def inside function definitions. When you are using def, you create a var in your namespace and possibly manipulate it as a side-effect with every function call. Use let-blocks.
- If you want to save Clojure data structures in a file, use `clojure.edn`. It is safe (e. g. without your knowledge, no functions defined in the file will be invoked) but it allows to enable custom readers (see more below).
- A type defined with defrecord can be printed in a (Clojure-reader-)readable way using `pr-str` (thanks to @A. Webb for noting that). In your example, I don't see why you would not stick to a hash-map in the first place, but if you really need a defrecord here, you may convert it into a readable string before your write it to the file.

  ```
  (defrecord Doodh [id name])

  (defn output [filename obj]
    (spit filename (pr-str obj))

  (defn pull [filename]
    (with-in-str (slurp filename)
                 (read)))
  ```

  - This way of doing it has several disadvantages.

    - Using `read` makes your code vulnerable to function calls in the slurped files (like `#=(java.lang.System/exit 0)`).
    - An exception will be thrown when the file at filename is empty.
    - Finally your saved file will become incompatible to your code when you move your defrecord declaration to another namespace.
    - All three disadvantages can be avoided by using the edn-reader.

**Using a custom reader with EDN**

1. We extend our type Doodh by implementing the toString method of the java.lang.Object interface:

   ```
   (defrecord Doodh [id name]
     Object
     (toString [this] (str "#Doodh" (into {} this))))
   ```
2. Because spit uses str, we can now omit the output function and simply invoke spit from e. g. the REPL:

   ```
   (spit "Doodh.edn" (map->Doodh {:id "134" :name "Berta"}))
   ```

   > Doodh.edn:
   >       #Doodh{:id 134, :name "Berta"}
3. Now to make sure that the Doodh will be read back, we invoke `clojure.edn/read-string` with a custom reader function:

   ```
   (defn pull [filename]
     (->> (slurp filename)
          (clojure.edn/read-string {:readers {'Doodh map->Doodh}})))
   ```
4. If you read back "Doodh.edn" using the new pull, you should receive a valid Doodh. At the REPL:

   ```
   (pull "Doodh.edn")
   => #user.Doodh{:id 134, :name "Berta"}
   ```

Comment: Which `*clojure-version* does your answer refer to? I think your third point may be out of date.

Comment: 1.5.1. Are you implying that it automatically chooses a reader-fn for #user.Doodh?

Comment: Oh, you are referring to the `edn` reader? No, but the [Clojure reader](http://clojure.org/reader) will call the constructor. The phrase "not be printed in a (Clojure-reader-)readable way" is the confusion.

Comment: In other words, `(with-in-str (pr-str (common.dummy.Doodh. "foo" "bar")) (clojure.core/read))` is the Clojure reader and works just fine. But, yes, `(with-in-str (pr-str (common.dummy.Doodh. "foo" "bar")) (clojure.edn/read))` will complain of no reader function for the edn.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. I did not know that the Clojure reader is capable of reading printed defrecords back. I will update my answer.

Comment: @lgrapenthin : Thanks for the EDN hint. It worked for me using the records. I need to use records and the code I wrote here was only to narrow down the problem into an isolated and easily readable section.

Comment: @A.Webb : Funny. I tried exactly what you said (with-in-str (pr-str (common.dummy.Doodh. "foo" "bar")) (clojure.core/read)) and I get the ** clojure.lang.LispReader$ReaderException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: common.dummy.Doodh ** error.
If it matters I am using Eclipse with Lein